# Spring Controller fails my CRUD Operations what can be done about this?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

This is picture of the error which the browser returns after trying to submit the user:

[image: 1]

Here is my Create method for Users also I use Repository for holding these methods.

```
private EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager();

    public String createUser(String account, String password) {
        Users user = new UsersEntity(account, password);

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        Query queryAccount = entityManager.createNativeQuery("Select * From Users Where Account = '" + account + "' ;",
                UsersEntity.class);
        List<Users> accountVerification = queryAccount.getResultList();

        Query queryPassword = entityManager
                .createNativeQuery("Select * From Users Where Password = '" + password + "' ;", UsersEntity.class);
        List<Users> passwordVerification = queryPassword.getResultList();

        if (accountVerification.size() != 0) {
            return "This username is already used! Try with another one!";
        } else if (passwordVerification.size() != 0) {
            return "This password is already used! Try with another one!";
        } else {
            entityManager.persist(user);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        entityManager.close();
        return "Sucessfull reccord!";
    }
```

Here is my Controller:

```
 @Controller
public class LibraryHelloWorld {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loginGet() {

        return new ModelAndView("LogInForm");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView loginPost(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(value = "firstname") String account,
            @RequestParam(value = "lastname") String password) {
        
        JPAUsersRepository userrep = new JPAUsersRepository();
        userrep.createUser(account.toString(), password.toString());

        return new ModelAndView("Sucessfull");
    }
```

In normal class creating of users is working fine but in this @Controller servlet in post method it throws exceptions:

```
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: test] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
Apr 29, 2017 12:10:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [library] in context with path [/Library] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:319)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1818)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1776)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at com.infoleven.utility.EntityManagerUtil.<clinit>(EntityManagerUtil.java:11)
    at com.infoleven.controller.LibraryHelloWorld.loginPost(LibraryHelloWorld.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apr 29, 2017 12:10:24 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
```

Here is also and my persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Library" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="notgame2" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults"
                value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

For DB I use local SQL Server. Create method is working correctly but not and in the current @Controller server

Comment: you dont seem to have lib containing the SQLServerDriver in your classpath. Double check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have correct JAR file in your CLASSPATH for **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver**

JAR file for that would be **sqljdbc41.jar**, if this is not in your CLASSPATH, then you have to add it. Hibernate will not provide 3rd party JAR files for JDBC Drivers.